# Accessing GridPanel base parameters

Tags: asp.net, gridpanel, ext.net

I have search box and a GridPanel with paging.  You enter search criteria click a button and the results display in the GridPanel...simple

I have notice a bug, when I search for something that returns 5 pages of records, go to the last page,  then perform another search that returns 1 page  I am on page 5 of 1.

The start page parameter is in the BaseParameters of the GridPanel,  how can I access this to reset it back to 0  when a new search is performed?

This is probably very easy but I am completely new to ext.net

Answer (score 0):

you can invoke the ***changePage()*** method of the **PagingToolbar**. This method excepts an Integer for the desired page number. Check out the link below for more details.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.PagingToolbar-method-changePage

Thanks,

Gav